# Powershell script path with spaces and arguments

Tags: c++, powershell

I am using `createProcess` to run a powershell script from C++ code.

However my script path contains spaces. And I need to pass one argument to the script. When there is no spaces in the path, below code works.

```
CString sysCommand;
sysCommand.Format(_T("powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted /C %s 
%s"), psFile, parameter);
```

I tried adding quotes around the path but then it stops recognizing the parameter and gives unexpected token error :

```
CString sysCommand;
sysCommand.Format(_T("powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted /C '%s' 
%s"), psFile, parameter);
```

Comment: Please post the *exact* error. Have you tried with double quotes (windows command line itself does not know single quotes, I think)? Also better specify what `/c` is supposed to do as it's not a standard easily discoverable argument for PS.

Comment: I did a workaround to fix it temporarily -
called cmd rather than calling pwershell.
    sysCommand.Format(_T("cmd.exe /C %s %s"), batFile, parameter);
and my bat file is - 

set ROOT=%~dp0

cd %ROOT%

call powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted .\department.ps1 parameter

Comment: Might just be as simple as escaping the double quotes that are within the string (your powershell command) like  `\"%s\"` ?